# What do equilibria tell you about limits and bounds of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Take as an example $y'= (y^2-1)e^{y-1}$ with $y(o)=1$. I understand the idea that there are two "equilibrium" solutions $y=1$ and $y=-1$. However, I can't seem to understand how to draw conclusions about the behavior of any solution at infinity or negative infinity or understand the bounds of any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic principles are:

1. If you start at an equilibrium, you stay there.  That's what equilibrium means.  So in your case if $1$ is an equilibrium and $y(0)=1$, the solution is $y(t)=1$ and its limits as $t \to \pm \infty$ are $1$.
2. Solutions never meet or cross.  So a solution that is less than a certain equilibrium solution at one time will always be less than that equilibrium solution.  Similarly for "greater than".
3. The equilibrium solutions divide the real line into intervals.  In each interval the right side of the differential equation is either always positive or always negative, corresponding to solutions increasing or decreasing.
4. An increasing function must either have a finite limit or go to $+\infty$ as $t \to +\infty$, and either have a finite limit or go to $-\infty$ as $t \to -\infty$.  Similarly for decreasing, with $t \to+\infty$ and $t \to -\infty$ reversed.  A finite limit must be an equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @MR1992: In that case, you should upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: I'm actually now wondering about (1): take $y'=y^{1/2}$ and $y(0)=0$. Isn't $y=(1/4)t^2$ a solution but not constant?

Comment: The "fine print" is that (1) and (2) depend on the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem, which requires the right side to be locally Lipschitz in $y$.